# setting session variable using ajax on drop down list

Tags: php, ajax

Guys this is driving me crazy. Everyone closing my question saying its been asked but I am unable to get it correct as I am new to ajax and php.

I am making a ajax call on drop down select event :

```
$('#username').change(function () {
    var user = $('#username').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'sessionvar.php',
        data: {username: user},
        success: function (msg) {
          alert('Success');
        }
  });
});
```

I am getting success alert. 
But on php page the variable is not getting set.

PHP code is:

```
<?php
session_start();
if( isset($_POST['username']) ){
    $_SESSION['cellValue'] = $_POST['username'];
}else{
    $_SESSION['cellValue'] = "good";
}

echo $_SESSION['cellValue'];
?>
```

Code is always printing value good.

My whole html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FusionCharts Column 2D Sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            session_start();
        ?>
        <div>
         // This will echo a select with name username. and when a value is
         // selected the below ajax call is made.
            <?php
                require("userList.php");
            ?>
        </div>
        <button type="button">Click Me</button>
        <div id="chart-container">LOADING....</div>
        <script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.js"/>
        <script src="js/fusioncharts.js"/>
        <script src="js/fusioncharts.charts.js"/>
        <script src="js/themes/fusioncharts.theme.zune.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

   $('#username').change(function () {
    var user = $('#username').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'sessionvar.php',
        data: {username: user},
        success: function (msg) {
          alert(msg);
        }
  });

});
   });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is msg variable value? do console.log(msg);

Comment: @Anant I have added session start on that page.

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap msg value is the data i am sending i.e. username value.

Comment: Do a console.log(user) before sending the ajax request. Check if the user variable actually getting the value.  The echo the $_POST['username'] to check if that was set at the time of ajax call.

Comment: then what the problem all code working fine.. you getting username as you send and as per your post page condition

Comment: @Anant i tried that i am getting the username value what i am sending its just the username is not setting. I have posted my whole html code can you see that i am doing some error I am starting session at the start.

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap problem is session variable is not setting up the if condition is failing on php side its somehow not getting the data. I have posted the html code may be you guys can point out some error.

Comment: @Anant I have updated the code with comment and simplified it.

Comment: session_start() should always be placed before your html code.

Comment: @ArjunChaudhary   session_start() should always be placed before your html code.  and after ajax call what you want?

Comment: i didnt get one thing you sent $_SESSION["username"] and assign to $_SESSION['cellValue'] via ajax and echo $_SESSION['cellValue']; in ajax and you are getting $_SESSION['username'] in success msg then what is the problem, variable successfully set and thats why it returning its values

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap when I am printing echo $_SESSION['cellValue']; its printing good instead of the sent value in $_POST

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
    $_SESSION['cellValue'] = $_POST['username'];
    echo $_SESSION['cellValue'];die;
}?>
<script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<select class="abc">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.abc').on('change', function() 
        {
             var user = $( ".abc option:selected" ).val();
             $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'test.php',
                    data: {username: user},
                    success: function (data) {
                      alert(data);
                    }
              });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: When you are selecting value you must be seeing an alert with values. But when you loading the php page are you seeing the username printed.

Comment: @Arjun according to your code i have put value in session and now i can get username after page reloaded